# Getters and Setters in Eclipse for Hungarian Style Members

Tags: java, eclipse, hungarian-notation

The project I'm working on dictates hungarian notation for class member variables. Example: `String m_foo;`

Is it possible to make Eclipse strip the hungarian prefix when generating getters and setters? I'm using Helios and it suggests (not surprisingly) `getM_foo` and `setM_foo`, but I want `getFoo` and `setFoo`. Code Templates doesn't look helpful.

Comment: ask if you can dispense with the hungarian and ask to dictate the use of getters and setters

Comment: Or you could probably create your own Eclipse plug-in to do this.

Comment: When I started the job I was told: Use our code style and do not even question it. xD

Answer (score 7):

In the preference page Java>Code Style, in the naming conventions table, select the "Fields" row, press the Edit button, and type "m_" in the Prefix list.

This also helps with Code Assist when generating fields.

You can also specify a prefix for static fields via the same table.

Answer (score 5):

Go to "Preferences". Find the node "Java" -> "Code Style". Add "m_" to the "Fields" as a prefix.

That should do it!