# How to make Eclipse strip underscores from getter/setters

Tags: java, eclipse, getter-setter, code-formatting

I'm trying to map json strings that use underscore naming convention to their corresponding java objects, the problem is the getters and setters get messy. For example

```
public static class ChargeState{

    private String charging_state;

    public String getCharging_state() {
        return charging_state;
    }
}
```

But what I want eclipse to generate

```
 public String getChargingState() {
        return charging_state;
    }
```

When I go into the preferences there is Java->Code Style->Code Templates

then for the setter body option it says
${field} = ${param};

Can i change this pattern or something to remove the underscore?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getters and Setters in Eclipse for Hungarian Style Members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784103/getters-and-setters-in-eclipse-for-hungarian-style-members)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, that is for having an underscore in the prefix of the variable.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you go to Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style and set the Fields prefix list to
'_' you will probably be able to do what your trying to achieve. If this doesn't help, maybe try [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784103/getters-and-setters-in-eclipse-for-hungarian-style-members)

Comment: Unfortunately, both ways you mentioned solve only "underscore in prefix" case. Not in the middle of the field's name, as OP asks.